# ArcGIS 10.2/10.2.1 for Desktop with Data Interoperablilty not seeing GPX files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, fme-form, gpx, data-interoperability

I have ArcGIS 10.2 and 10.2.1 both with Data Interoperablilty extension. But there is a problem with GPX files. ArcGIS simply doesn't see it. In 10.1 there was no problem to drag n drop them but now it's impossible. In quick import tool, when I open FME reader gallery I can't find gpx on the list. What's going on? Have you the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the GPX to Feature tool in the Arc Toolbox? It is located in the Conversion Tools > From GPS > GPX To Features.

If I attempt to drag and drop a .gpx file, a message that says 'Could not open the specified file' appears.

[image]

Try this then:  In ArcCatalog, click on Customize > ArcCatalog Options > Click on the File Types Tab and manually add in the .GPX file extension. The file will then be recognized.

[image]

Comment: GPX To feature works. But I cannot do drag n drop gpx (and I was doing it in 10.1) because In catalog window I cannot see gpx file. It seems like there is no support in data interopability extension for gpx file in ArcGIS 10.2 or 10.2.1. But I think it's impossible.

Comment: I just got around to trying it out and ArcCatalog still doesn't recognize the .gpx file even though it appears in the TOC.

Comment: I think the reason is no feedback for gpx file in the FME engine in data interopability. Check out pictures: [ArcGIS 10.1](http://i61.tinypic.com/4vrcky.jpg) and [ArcGIS 10.2](http://i57.tinypic.com/2z4zr85.jpg)